# Prove by mathematical induction from "Axiom II" that if $a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n$ are positive, then the sum $a_1+a_2+...a_n$ is positive.

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Axion II: If a and b are members of the set P of positive numbers, then the sum a+b and the product ab are members of the set P.

I'm not very familiar with mathematical induction, so here is my attempt:

Suppose n=1, then given that $a_1 \in P$ $a_1>0$

Suppose n=2 then given that $a_1,a_2\in P$ from Axiom II $a_1+a_2>0$

Assume from here that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_{n-1}>0$$

From Axion II if $a_n>0$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3+...a_{n-1}>0$ then adding the 2 inequalities $(a_1+a_2+a_3+...a_{n-1})+a_n>0$

Therefore $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n>0$$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1}$ is meaningless. Either write $a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1}$ or $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i$. Same in the last line.

Comment: (Ok, not quite meaningless, but not what you intended: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_1+\dots+a_{n-1}$ is either $(n-1)a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{n-1}$ or $(n-1)(a_1+\dots+a_{n-1})$ depending on whether we assume some parentheses or not.)

Comment: You're definitely on the right track. Good use of Induction. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it looks good! You can make it a little shorter by not considering the case $n=2$, since you only need $n=1$ as your base case.

You could also improve your wording and notation a bit. For instance, when you say "Therefore", it would be better to say something like "Therefore, by induction". Also, instead of writing "...from Axiom II $a_1+a_2>0$", perhaps include some words to separate II from the inequality, such as
"...from Axiom II, we obtain $a_1+a_2>0$." There are mainly stylistic remarks.

However, in regards to the notation, Andrés E. Caicedo already pointed out in the comments that you should have
$$ a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}>0$$
or
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i>0,$$
and not
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}.$$
Indeed, the latter is equal to $(n-1)(a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1})$, which isn't what you want.

Comment: If I dropped the case $n=2$, would it be better to show the base $n=1$ as being $a_1+0>0$ to make it clear that it's meant to be a sum leading to my assumption?

Comment: @Jon Well I think that would make it more confusing, since $a_1$ is a sum containing only one term, not a sum of a term and zero. The clearest way to explain it would be with words; eg. "The case $n=1$ follows because a sum containing only the positive term is certainly positive." If you want to use notation, perhaps you could write
$
a_1 = \sum_{i=1}^1 a_i.
$

Answer (score 0):

Here how to use correctly the mathematical induction.
Given $n_0\in \Bbb N $,
we need it to prove that
$$\forall n\ge n_0 \;\;P_n $$
where $P_n $ is a certain property which depends on $n $.

> first step

We check that $P_{n_0} $ is true.

> second

We say :

Let $n\ge n_0$ such that $P_n $, and we prove $P_{n+1} $.

Most of people, in the second step, say :

Assume $P_\color {red}{n} $ without defining what is $\color {red}{n} $.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "define" in the last sentence.